# Como remover alguns caracteres de uma var javascript?

Tags: javascript

Bom eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
var tempo = "Rolling in 8.31...";
```

O que pretendo é da string acima, deixar apenas o numero 8, de forma a que a var tempo, fique da seguinte maneira:

```
var tempo = "8";
```

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

@EDIT:

Código Atual:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
var tempo = document.getElementById("banner");


var match = tempo.match(/[^\d](\d+)/);
var nr = match && match[1];

console.log(nr);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Tens sempre o mesmo texto `Rolling in `? ou o texto pode variar? podes dar mais exemplos?

Comment: O texto, é sempre o mesmo, a unica coisa que pode variar é o 8.31, eu queria que tudo desaparece e so ficasse o 8. Pode ser por exemplo 10.20, 15.23 etc... Ou seja, pretendo tirar as casas decimais e os restantes caracteres. E deixar somente o numero principal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes criar uma regex para procurar o primeiro numero:

```js
var tempo = "Rolling in 8.31...";
var match = tempo.match(/[^\d](\d+)/);
var nr = match && match[1];
console.log(nr); // 8
```

Ou cortar a string com um slice:

```js
var tempo = "Rolling in 8.31...";
var nr = parseInt(tempo.slice(11), 10);
console.log(nr); // 8
```

Nos exemplos extrai-se o numero. No primeiro como *String* no segundo como *Number*. Vê o que preferes e se necessário converte para o tipo correto.

Comment: Esta-me a dar o erro tempo.match is not a function

Comment: @Gonçalo O que te dá `console.log(typeof tempo, tempo)`?

Comment: Not defined, vou atualizar a pergunta com o meu codigo atual. Estou a experimentar o codigo neste site: www.csgopolygon.com no console.

Comment: @Gonçalo Não consigo carregar esse link, mas se tens um elemento tens de usar o `innerHTML` ou `textContent` para ter o conteúdo. Por exemplo: `var tempo = document.getElementById("banner").textContent;`

Comment: Perfeito, Obrigado mais uma vez Sergio!